# Spinnaker + AWS Autoscaling life cycle hooks

Tags: autoscaling, spinnaker

I heard that Spinnaker is not able to handle AWS Autoscaling life cycle.
Is that true? If so, is there any plan or roadmap to support this function?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroupLifecycle.html

I will move this post if it is not related to this page. Welcome any technical advice or helpful link to refer.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not correct. You can specify lifecycle hooks as part of your credentials definition and Spinnaker will add these hooks to the ASGs deployed to that account.

Here is an example definition from our config. This is a list so you can have more than one.

`lifecycleHooks:
  - lifecycleTransition: autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATING
    notificationTargetARN: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxx:eureka-prod-autoscaling-lifecycles
    heartbeatTimeout: 120
    defaultResult: CONTINUE`